# Trying to make an object, use it and then store it a list using a single statement

Tags: java

I have following set of data in java

```java
class TestClass {
    public void testMethod(String input) {
        // do some operations
    }
}


class Implementation {
    TestClass t1;

    ArrayList<TestClass> listofClass = new ArrayList<TestClass>();

    void implementationMethod() {
        t1 = new TestClass();
        t1.testMethod("hello");
        listofClass.add(t1);

        t1 = new TestClass();
        t1.testMethod("bye");
        listofClass.add(t1);
    }
}
```

Now the above section of code is working fine where I'm creating a new object, using it to call the method and storing the object in a list. The thing I want is to do these 3 step-process in a single step. Reason is I am going to do this multiple times and this will become quite long and unmanageable.
Maybe could be done with lambda(not sure).
Thank you.

Comment: Create a new method `private void addNewTestClass(String input) { var t = new TestClass(); t.testMethod(input); listOfClass.add(t); }`

Comment: Maybe you can add a [`String`] parameter to `TestClass` constructor and call method `testMethod` from that constructor? Then you could simply do: `listOfClass.add(new TestClass("hello"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your method return a reference to its own object. Change your return type from `void`.

```java
class TestClass {
    public TestClass testMethod(String input) {
        // do some operations
        return this ;  // Provide for method-chaining. 
    }
}
```

```java
listofClass.add( new TestClass().testMethod( "bye ") );
```

See [method-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) in Wikipedia.

Comment: This works. I used it with method chaining. Thank you.